# Tensorflow dataset pipeline for large HDF5 file

Tags: tensorflow, dataset

Let's say I have 10 million training samples stored in a HDF5 file and I want to generate batches of size 1000 with a TensorFlow dataset. However, the 10 million samples are too big to be loaded in memory.

What I want to do is to load the numpy data from the HDF5 in memory 1 million at a time, and then iterate to generate my batches of size 1000. When the 1 million samples are finished, I want to load the next 1 million from the HDF5 and continue. I would like to managed this with a single Dataset in tensorflow.

However, I don't see how to do this with the Dataset API from tensorflow.

How can I iterate on two levels like this (1st level=big chunks of 1 million, 2nd level=small batches of 1000).

Thanks

Comment: Is there any particular necessity that you need to read 1 million at a time?
[from_generator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator) method is generally used to read data from large datasets that dont fit in memory. [batch](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#batch) can then be applied to batch your data to the size you require.